# How get a union of descendant names with a recursive generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type object of nodes, many of which specify other nodes as children. For example:

```
type Nodes = {
  a: {
    children: ["b"]
  },
  b: {
    children: ["c"]
  },
  c: {
    children: []
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a generic type, something like `type DescendantName<T extends keyof Nodes> = ...` that produces a union of the descendant names of `Nodes[T]`, such that `DescendantName<"a">` produces `"b" | "c"`.

I tried a straightforward recursive syntax but got a circularity type error:

```
type DescendantName<T extends keyof Nodes> = Nodes[T]["children"][number] | DescendantName<Nodes[T]["children"][number]>
// Type alias 'DescendantName' circularly references itself. ts(2456)
```

Can anyone tell me how to make a working generic type like this?

Comment: Why you need `DescendantName<Nodes[T]["children"][number]>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one-liner version

```
type DescendantName<T extends keyof Nodes> = Nodes[T]["children"][number] extends never 
    ? never 
    : Nodes[T]["children"][number] | DescendantName<Nodes[T]["children"][number]>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgZygXigbwFBSgQwC4tc8oBjACwEsAbBAJwgDtiBtAIgCMOBdUgL4AaUl2I4yFGvSasoncn0Ei85caVXTGLdvzwDsB7KEhQAIinIsE%20ZsBj4AthAA8AFSgQAHsGuoA1hAgcABmsIgoAHzo4UjIbG68ClqyfGzMAK6OXBAMvJ4%20flDMEABuuVAaUAD8xWUVVcTwcQlJHFR02sxpmdm5%20QA%205pbWtvZOrs0orcmdqUm9OXmR2Ksm0ACCtLQWVsw2dg7OqBgWyHsH484uHPgcK9hAA)

---

There are a few other "Features" to this implementation that may or may not be what you are looking for:

It will throw an error if there is an invalid child node in children

```
type Nodes = {
  a: {
    children: ["b"]
  },
  b: {
    children: ["c"]
  },
  c: {
    children: ["d"] // "d" is not in Nodes
  }
}

type DescendantName<T extends keyof Nodes> = Nodes[T]["children"][number] extends never 
    ? never 
    : Nodes[T]["children"][number] | DescendantName<Nodes[T]["children"][number]>
// Type 'Nodes[T]["children"][number]' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof Nodes'.
//   Type '"b" | "c" | "d"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Nodes'.
//     Type '"d"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Nodes'.(2344)
```

It will also throw an error if there is a loop

```
type Nodes = {
  a: {
    children: ["b"]
  },
  b: {
    children: ["c"]
  },
  c: {
    children: ["a"] // a -> b -> c -> a -> and so on...
  }
}

type DescendantName<T extends keyof Nodes> = Nodes[T]["children"][number] extends never 
    ? never 
    : Nodes[T]["children"][number] | DescendantName<Nodes[T]["children"][number]>


type AllDecendantNames = DescendantName<"a">
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Ahhh nice, simpler than my solution

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the following to work. I think the key is making sure to only do the recursive call if the child node type is a key of `Nodes`.

Here's [the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgZygXigbwFBSgQwC4tc8oBjACwEsAbBAJwgDtiBtAIgCMOBdUgL4AaUl2I4yFGvSasoncn0Ei85caVXTGLdvzwDsB7KEhQAIinIsE+ZsBj4AthAA8AFSgQAHsGuoA1hAgcABmsIgoAHzo4UjIbG68ClqyfGzMAK6OXBAMvFAAPlAAwlrwcS7lKAlJHFR02sxpmdm5vJEA3Mbg0KUNVcju0Rge3r7MCAFBobEoUAD85pbWtvZOrm7RxMwQAG65XdjkcMzIwFC+Z8QWyFYTqw7OLhz4HMNQ3BxAA).

```js
type Nodes = {
  a: {
    children: ["b"]
  },
  b: {
    children: ["c"]
  },
  c: {
    children: []
  }
}

type DescendantName<T extends keyof Nodes> = Nodes[T]["children"][number] | ChildNodes<Nodes[T]["children"][number]>;
type ChildNodes<T> = T extends keyof Nodes ? DescendantName<T> : never;

const test: DescendantName<"a"> = "b"
```